# displaying the rows and columns of the Jbutton pressed

Tags: java, user-interface, jbutton, actionlistener

I am working on this game board where i have created a 5x5 Jbuttons board.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*; // Needed for ActionListener and ActionEvent
import javax.swing.*; // Needed for JFrame and JButton

public class boardGame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
//colours variable
private Color[] colors;
// This stores all buttons
JButton[][] buttons = new JButton[5][5];
String[] buttonLabels = { "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""};

public boardGame(String title) {
super(title);
setLayout(null);

Color[] colors = new Color[4];

//Initialize the values of the array
colors[0] = Color.red;
colors[1] = Color.blue;
colors[2] = Color.yellow;
colors[3] = Color.green;


for(int row=0; row<5; row++) {
    for (int col=0; col<5; col++) {
        buttons[row][col] = new JButton(buttonLabels[row*5+col]);
        buttons[row][col].setLocation(10+col*55, 10+row*55);
        buttons[row][col].setSize(50,50);
        buttons[row][col].addActionListener(this);

        buttons[row][col].setBackground(colors[new Random().nextInt(4)]);

        add(buttons[row][col]);
    }
}

//labels
JLabel label1 = new JLabel("COL: ");
label1.setLocation(10,260);
label1.setSize(100,100);
add(label1);

JLabel label2 = new JLabel("ROW: ");
label2.setLocation(10,280);
label2.setSize(100,100);
add(label2);

setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setSize(305,395);
}


// This is the single event handler for all the buttons
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
JButton selectedBtn = (JButton) e.getSource();

for (int row = 0; row < buttons.length; row++) {
  for (int col = 0; col < buttons[row].length; col++) {
    if (buttons[row][col] == selectedBtn) {
      System.out.printf("Selected row and column: %d %d%n", row+1, col+1);
       }
     }
   }
 }

public static void main(String args[]) {
boardGame frame = new boardGame("The Board Game");
frame.setVisible(true);  
}
```

}

I am new to this action command and action listener (mouse pressed) event. You must have noticed i used this in my code:

```
// This is the single event handler for all the buttons
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
JButton selectedBtn = (JButton) e.getSource();

for (int row = 0; row < buttons.length; row++) {
  for (int col = 0; col < buttons[row].length; col++) {
    if (buttons[row][col] == selectedBtn) {
      System.out.printf("Selected row and column: %d %d%n", row+1, col+1);
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

this piece of code is displaying the rows and columns of the button pressed correctly. but what i'm trying to do is that i'm trying to display this information in front of my Jlabels.

i.e if a button is pressed and it lies on a row 2 and column 4 it should show it like this :

[image]

```
//labels
JLabel label1 = new JLabel("COL: ");
label1.setLocation(10,260);
label1.setSize(100,100);
add(label1);

JLabel label2 = new JLabel("ROW: ");
label2.setLocation(10,280);
label2.setSize(100,100);
add(label2);
```

any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

You have button, so you need to use the method setBackground( YOUR COLOR HERE)
so your solution can be: **generate a random number between 0 and 3** (for your array of colors...)

## Example:

```
for(int row=0; row<5; row++) {
  for (int col=0; col<5; col++) {
    buttons[row][col] = new JButton(buttonLabels[row*5+col]);
    buttons[row][col].setLocation(10+col*55, 10+row*55);
    buttons[row][col].setSize(50,50);
    buttons[row][col].addActionListener(this);
   
    buttons[row][col].setBackground(colors[new Random().nextInt(4)]);  ///this will do the trick..
    
    add(buttons[row][col]);
  }
}
```

---

## Edit:

If you need to get the "Coordinates of the clicked button" then in the `actionPerformed`  do the reverse math to get the x and y of the button.

## Example2:

```
Point p = btn1.getLocation();
int xCoordinates = (p.x - 10) / 55;
int yCoordinates = (p.x - 10) / 55;
System.out.println("Here is x: " + xCoordinates);
System.out.println("Here is y: " + yCoordinates);
```

Comment: thank you @Xoce. it actually did the trick.
now i am only concerned about the second part of my question: which is how to get the row number and column number after pressing a Jbutton. any ideas on that one?

Comment: Ummm, ok, I have no idea what you are doing, but I can imagine your array of buttons like a squared matrix, AND, the best part, you are doing this: ***setLocation(10+col*55, 10+row*55)***, so I will modify my answer so you can test...

Comment: I update my answer, please take a look an let me know

Comment: your example 2 does give me a sound idea on how to approach on this now so thanks for that but i'm still having a bit a trouble here. my code mentions 2 Jlabels ROW and COL respectively. when i press a button i am trying to show which row and column does this button belongs to and show it infront of my labels.
any ideas about that?