# Finding JButton co-ordinates

Tags: java

This question relates to the previous one. It's almost the same program. I wanted to print out the seat number for the selected seat but I can't figure out how. If I could get the row number and column number for the selected seat I could print out the seat number.Can anyone help me ?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.io.File;
class silver1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener { 
    private JButton[] bt = new JButton[1]; 

    JFrame fr=new JFrame();

    static int c=250;
    static int j1=1;
    static int c11=680;
   static int k=105;
   static int k11=295;
   static int sum=0;
   static int s;
   static int j;

  public silver1() throws IOException{ 





  JLabel l1=new JLabel();
  JLabel l2=new JLabel();
  JLabel l3=new JLabel();
  JLabel l4=new JLabel(); 
  JPanel p1=new JPanel();
  JPanel p2=new JPanel();
  JPanel p3=new JPanel();
  JPanel p4=new JPanel();
  l1.setText("<html><font size=7><font color=white>Select Your Seats</html>");
  l2.setText("<html><font size=5><font color=white>All Eyes This Way Please!!</html>");
  l3.setText("<html><font size=5><font color=white>GOLD</html>");
  l4.setText("<html><font size=5><font color=white>SILVER</html>");
  p2.setBackground(Color.gray);
  p3.setBackground(Color.gray);
  p4.setBackground(Color.gray);
  p1.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
  fr.add(l2);
  fr.add(p2);
  fr.add(l1);
  fr.add(p1);
  fr.add(l3);
  fr.add(p3);
  fr.add(l4);
  fr.add(p4);
  l1.setBounds(450,15,590,40);
  p1.setBounds(1,1,3400,75);
  p2.setBounds(300,605,650,35);
  l2.setBounds(500,605,650,35);
  l3.setBounds(636,80,80,25);
  p3.setBounds(636,80,55,25);
  p4.setBounds(625,265,70,25);
  l4.setBounds(625,265,80,25);
  fr.setLayout(null); 


  for(s=1;s<=4;s++,k+=40)
  {
     c=250;c11=680;
     for(j=1;j<=10;j++,c+=40)
       {
          for (int i = 0; i < bt.length; i++,j1++) { 
          JLabel lab=new JLabel();

          bt[i] = new JButton(Integer.toString(j1));

          bt[i].setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
          bt[i].setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
           fr.add(bt[i]); 
           Border noBorder = new LineBorder(Color.WHITE, 0);
           bt[i].setBorder(noBorder);
          bt[i].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
          //bt[i].addActionListener(this); 
          bt[i].setBounds(c,k,40,40);
      } 
    }
    for(j=1;j<=10;j++,c11+=40)
       {
          for (int i = 0; i < bt.length; i++,j1++) { 

          bt[i] = new JButton(Integer.toString(j1));

          bt[i].setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
          bt[i].setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
          fr.add(bt[i]); 
           Border noBorder = new LineBorder(Color.WHITE, 0);
           bt[i].setBorder(noBorder);
          bt[i].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
          //bt[i].addActionListener(this); 
          bt[i].setBounds(c11,k,40,40);



        }
      }
    }

    for(s=1;s<=7;s++,k11+=40)
  {
     c=250;c11=680;
     for(j=1;j<=10;j++,c+=40)
       {
          for (int i = 0; i < bt.length; i++,j1++) { 
          JLabel lab=new JLabel();

          bt[i] = new JButton(Integer.toString(j1));

          bt[i].setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
          bt[i].setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
           fr.add(bt[i]); 
           Border noBorder = new LineBorder(Color.WHITE, 0);
           bt[i].setBorder(noBorder);
          bt[i].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
          bt[i].addActionListener(this); 
          bt[i].setBounds(c,k11,40,40);

      } 
    }
    for(j=1;j<=10;j++,c11+=40)
       {
          for (int i = 0; i < bt.length; i++,j1++) { 

          bt[i] = new JButton(Integer.toString(j1));

          bt[i].setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
          bt[i].setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
          fr.add(bt[i]); 
           Border noBorder = new LineBorder(Color.WHITE, 0);
           bt[i].setBorder(noBorder);
          bt[i].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
          bt[i].addActionListener(this); 
          bt[i].setBounds(c11,k11,40,40);



        }
      }
    }

      int k1=105;
      char a='A';
      for(int s1=1;s1<=12;s1++,k1+=40,a++)
      {
          if(a=='E')
          {k1-=10;
              continue; }
          JLabel label=new JLabel();
          label.setText(a+"");
          fr.add(label);
          label.setBounds(220,k1,40,40);
        }


       JButton b1=new JButton("<html><font size=5><font color=white>BACK </html>");       
    b1.addActionListener(new Action());
    b1.setBackground(Color.RED);        
    fr.add(b1);     
    b1.setBounds(4,82,90,30);

     fr.setVisible(true); 
     fr.pack();
     fr.setSize(new Dimension(3400,765));

     c=250;
     c11=680;
    k=105;
    k11=295;

 } 


 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

JButton pressedButton = (JButton)e.getSource();
if(pressedButton.getBackground() == Color.GREEN){ 
    if(sum != 0)
    {

   JLabel l=new JLabel();  
   JPanel p=new JPanel();
   pressedButton.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
   sum--;
   l.setText("<html><font size=7><font color= white>Number of Seats Selected: "+sum+"");       


   p.add(l);
   p.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
   fr.add(p);
   l.setBounds(390,15,590,40);
   p.setBounds(1,1,3400,75);
}
else 
{
     JLabel l=new JLabel();         
   pressedButton.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
   sum--;
   l.setText("<html><font size=5>Select Your Seats"+""); 

   fr.add(l);
   l.setBounds(390,25,290,75);              
}
}else if(pressedButton.getBackground() == Color.WHITE){ 
   JLabel l=new JLabel();  
   JPanel p=new JPanel();
   pressedButton.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
   sum++;
   l.setText("<html><font size=7><font color= white>Number of Seats Selected: "+sum+"");

   p.add(l);
   p.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
   fr.add(p);
   l.setBounds(390,15,590,40);
   p.setBounds(1,1,3400,75);
}else{ 
   pressedButton.setBackground(Color.WHITE); 
} 
if(sum>-1)
{
    JButton b1=new JButton("<html><font size=5><font 
    color=white>BOOK</html>");       
    b1.addActionListener(new Actionn());
    b1.setBackground(Color.BLUE);        
    fr.add(b1);     
    b1.setBounds(4,132,90,30);
    if(sum==0)
    fr.remove(b1);

  }
}
 class Action implements ActionListener
 {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    { 
        }
}
class Actionn implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    { 

        }
  }
} 
 public class silver { 
  public static void main() throws IOException
  {
     silver1 bcts = new silver1();  
  } 
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [displaying the rows and columns of the Jbutton pressed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35923751/displaying-the-rows-and-columns-of-the-jbutton-pressed)

Comment: TL;DR. Please provide [mcve]